# $V$ is Compactly Embbeded in it self?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, compactness, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Can we say that $V$ is compactly embbeded in it self

$$V=\left\{u\in H^{1}\left(\Omega\right):\gamma_{0}\left(u\right)=0 \text{ on } \Gamma_{0}\right\}$$

I would like to use aubin-lions theorem.

Comment: The identity map $\mathrm{id}:V\to V$ can never be a compact embedding if $V$ is infinite dimensional. If you want a compact embedding of $V$ into itself you will need to take another map.

Comment: Is there another space which can embedded compactly in V?

Comment: Well yeah, many spaces admit compact embeddings into other spaces. Natural or good embeddings depend on the context and the issue under consideration. At any rate I'm not too familiar with the particulars of Sobolev spaces to give you any natural embeddings here.

Comment: In Aubin-Lions you mostly use that $V$ is compactly embedded in $L^2$. Now, if you want another space that embeds compactly in $V$, take e.g. $H^2$ with zero on $\Gamma_0$.